# Want to add form field  and get it in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I was looking how to add image to the form then I found [These codes](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/upload-image.shtml). While integrating this code I failed because I have other fields in the form to be posted when the form is submitted.

So can you please help me to  post for instance a field **Lastname** along with the file and show how can I get it it( Block of code in the servlet to get the lastname) using the same servlet.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code (e.g. html form and servlet)!

Comment: Warning: roseindia.net is one of the **worst** sites when it comes to "best practices" (in other words, that site is so full of *bad* practices). Be extremely careful when copypasting examples unmodified and make sure that you have also consulted vendor's own official documentation such as [here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing Apache Commons FileUpload **and** Servlet 3.0 `@MultipartConfig`. Those two are entirely distinct ways to parse `multipart/form-data` requests. A HTTP request can be parsed only once. So if one of those two ways has already parsed it beforehand, the other way would not be able to parse it anymore and end up with null/empty data.

You should use the one *or* the other way to parse the request and not both ways. Apache Commons FileUpload was the "de facto" standard to parse `multipart/form-data` requests before Servlet 3.0 was introduced (Dec 2009). But since Servlet 3.0 there's the new `@MultipartConfig` annotation and the new `request.getPart()` method which makes Apache Commons FileUpload superfluous.

When using Apache Commons FileUpload, you should **remove** the Servlet 3.0 `@MultipartConfig` and all `request.getParameter()` lines and extract the "regular" request parameters from the `List items` instead.

When using Servlet 3.0 `@MultipartConfig`, you should **remove** all code related to Apache Commons FileUpload and use `request.getPart()` instead to obtain the uploaded file.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: Ok The annotation @MultipartConfig was used because previous I failed. previously It was like you see after removing the annotation.

Comment: I see that you removed it from your question as well (you actually shouldn't do that as that would lead to confusion among future readers...). In your real code you should by the way also have removed all `request.getParameter()` lines and use Apache Commons FileUpload exclusively to get the regular parameters, exactly as stated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for see also , First   I realized the error of using request.getParameter because the form without the file worked well, but after the file has been added it returned null to all field.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand my answer at all, most likely because you don't understand the "under the hoods" workings at all. I'd suggest to carefully read the "See also" link at the bottom of my answer to understand how exactly uploading files works. Once again, to fix your problem you should **remove** all `request.getParameter()` lines (because they parse the request before Apache Commons FileUpload get chance to do so!) and extract them using Apache Commons FileUpload instead.

Comment: Ok I understood and even if I didn't do automatically, as you see in my previous message I wrote that after removing it in my local machine. So What I need now is to get clear field names usin FileItem

Comment: Thank you @BalusC for your answers. Now I am uploading and displaying images. My questions were solved successfully.

Comment: Ok I was asking myself how to mark the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @BalusC but how do you get the form fields values uploaded together with the image? I believe this is what the OP was asking but if you answered it I didn't get it.

Comment: @qualebs: it's detailed in the answer behind the "See also" link.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing, you want to use the apache commons fileupload library in the servlet and do something like this to grab the image file upload.

```
            DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory ();


        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
        try {
            /*
             * Parse the request
             */
            List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator itr = items.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
                /*
                 * Handle Form Fields.
                 */
                if(item.isFormField()) {
                    //do stuff here if the item currently is not a file upload
                } 
                                else {
              //DO stuff here to handle the file upload 
                                 }
```

Comment: See the complete form and servlet. Thanks